# Save list to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, code-behind

This is what I have so far:

```
Veza.Open();
SqlCommand zadnjaN = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 id_n FROM Narudzba ORDER BY id_n DESC", Veza);
var id_zn = zadnjaN.ExecuteScalar(); //get 1 value for id_zn (last one entered)
List<int> proizvodi = new List<int>();
proizvodi = (List<int>)Session["kosarica"];
SqlCommand kupnja1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO NarudzbaItemi ([narudzbaID], [proizvodID]) VALUES (@id_zn, @pro)", Veza);
for (int i = 0; i < proizvodi.Count; i++)
{
  kupnja1.Parameters.AddWithValue("pro", proizvodi[i]); //also tried @pro
  kupnja1.Parameters.AddWithValue("id_zn", id_zn); //@id_zn
  kupnja1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
Veza.Close();
```

I get a message saying that variable name @pro has allready been declared.
The point is, I need to insert a list of int items into column proizvodID, and however many times I insert a value in that column I need to insert an unchanging value that many times in column narudzbaID, which I get from a different table as the last value added. All 3 columns are int, and Session is List int. Using asp.net, c#, sql server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you can do this. But John Saunders's method is better I think

```
    for (int i = 0; i < proizvodi.Count; i++)
    {
        //Add this line to clear parameters
        kupnja1.Parameters.Clear();
        kupnja1.Parameters.AddWithValue("pro", proizvodi[i]); //also tried @pro
        kupnja1.Parameters.AddWithValue("id_zn", id_zn); //@id_zn
        kupnja1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You keep adding parameters in the loop. On the second iteration, `@pro` *is* already defined.

Try this:

```
Veza.Open();
object id_zn; //get 1 value for id_zn (last one entered)
using (SqlCommand zadnjaN = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 id_n FROM Narudzba ORDER BY id_n DESC", Veza))
{
    id_zn = zadnjaN.ExecuteScalar();
}
List<int> proizvodi = (List<int>)Session["kosarica"];
using (SqlCommand kupnja1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO NarudzbaItemi ([narudzbaID], [proizvodID]) VALUES (@id_zn, @pro)", Veza))
{
    kupnja1.Parameters.Add("pro"); 
    kupnja1.Parameters.Add("id_zn");
    for (int i = 0; i < proizvodi.Count; i++)
    {
        kupnja1.Parameters["pro"].Value = proizvodi[i]; //also tried @pro
        kupnja1.Parameters["id_zn"].Value = id_zn; //@id_zn
        kupnja1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
Veza.Close();
```

Comment: You can still use addwithValue for id_zn, no ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: true, but why bother? Consistency is better.

Comment: Well, this is a point of view. On another hand, the other way helps to understand what change and what doesn't. Anyway, really detail...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: "what changed"? Once the code is written, this will not be a "change". Code for the steady state (most of the time).

Comment: I just mean : when I have two vars. 1 has a value which change in a loop, the other will be the same for all the loop's iterations : I assign the non-changing var's value outside of the loop.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: Oh, I see. Good idea, but I'd still use separate `Parameters.Add` and `.Value=`, for consistency.

Comment: That's the best compromise, I think ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's basically saying you can't keep reusing the same command, this should work, moving the declaration into the loop:

```
    Veza.Open();
    SqlCommand zadnjaN = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 id_n FROM Narudzba ORDER BY id_n DESC", Veza);
    var id_zn = zadnjaN.ExecuteScalar(); //get 1 value for id_zn (last one entered)
    List<int> proizvodi = new List<int>();
    proizvodi = (List<int>)Session["kosarica"];

    for (int i = 0; i < proizvodi.Count; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand kupnja1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO NarudzbaItemi ([narudzbaID], [proizvodID]) VALUES (@id_zn, @pro)", Veza);
        kupnja1.Parameters.AddWithValue("pro", proizvodi[i]); //also tried @pro
        kupnja1.Parameters.AddWithValue("id_zn", id_zn); //@id_zn
        kupnja1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    Veza.Close();
```

Comment: -1: if you're going to put the command instantiation in the loop, then you _for sure_ must dispose of the command when done!

Comment: @John And -1 to you too, I'll correct SQL injection but I don't lecture new programmers about using `using`, it's not necessary to get the program working, just good practice. The guy's asking about the basics, why overwhelm him?

Comment: `using` is basic, especially in a loop. Be careful about the code you post: people copy it.

Comment: @John Go test it. C# can easily handle you not using `using` on `SqlCommand`. Just like you rarely put a using on an entity connection. It's not a massive problem. `SqlConnection` is the actually important one. It's as dogmatic as saying that you should always use `StringBuilder`. Go have a peek in reflector if you're still doubting disposing a `SqlCommand` isn't particularly important. There's no *for sure* about it.

Comment: In my frequently-expressed opinion, it's _for sure_ that it's better to get developers in the habit of implementing `using` blocks because they _will_ get into situations where they start getting strange errors because of failing to do so. No need to discuss this any further, you're not being singled out - I've done this to many people before you.

Comment: @John Then don't do it again, you just ruined what is supposed to be an enjoyable way of helping people for a totally stupid and bogus reason. I've been annoyed about it all day. Keep your dogmatic coding opinions for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: You're slipping towards rudeness by telling me what to do. That doesn't work well. Have a nice day. Alternatively, you could fix your code and I'd remove the downvote. You could _still_ have a nice day.

Comment: @John But that's exactly what you did to me in your first comment?